# AWS S3 credentials problem log message but S3Client.putObject() succeeds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

On Windows 10 I'm using the AWS S3 Java SDK v2, Maven coordinates `software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.7.5` (from `software.amazon.awssdk:bom`). I have my credentials stored in `~user/.aws/credentials`.

As per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html), the I use an `S3Client.putObject()` to put an object in a bucket. I get two `DEBUG` level log messages from `software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProviderChain`:

> `software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).`

However `S3Client.putObject()` succeeds.

Don't I have my credentials configured properly by putting them in `~user/.aws/credentials`? Why is this error being logged? I realize that it is a `DEBUG` level message, but it clutters up the log, not only once but twice. Plus there was no problem; the credentials were configured correctly.

Is there some way to turn off this log message? Or is there some extra configuration step I'm not doing correctly?

*Update:* It appears that this debug message is only generated once for the creation of the S3 client, so it's not as intrusive as it appears. Still it's more cluttered than desired to log an exception for only a warning condition, even though it's only at a `DEBUG` level.

Comment: I don't get it, I've answered just what your edit says 3 days before...

Comment: I was pointing out that the message is only generated once for the creation of the client, not with each client request. @Pablo Recalde, you didn't mention that in your answer, so I was giving an update on my findings. In any case, the question was how to turn this off, which no one has yet answered. I know I can turn off all debug messages, but that's not the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common *error message* when you’re using ENV vars to provide your service with an AMI account (accessid-accesskey combination) as you’ve mentioned is DEBUG. I don’t usually use this log level on environments except for development.

Anyway you can configure different log levels for different namespaces, Generally I tend to use “Information” on third party libraries (except for Entity framework that always gets set to Error because of its verbosity).